# PhpStorm updates the web AUTOMATICALLY when making changes

Tags: php, deployment, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've been working with **PhpStorm** for a few months and without the need to save, it already automatically updates any change I make on the production website. This leads to numerous problems and headaches, since sometimes it does not save correctly, it deletes what I have written, it includes lines that I wrote seconds ago, it copies and pastes old lines... Depending on the speed of my connection and that of the server, this tends to increase.

The time wasted using this tool is considerable, and I was wondering **if there was an option to NOT update changes in real time**. I want them to update ONLY on save or some other manual way that saves me from this hassle when programming.

Thanks.

I've searched the internet but can't find anything on this.
Unfortunately I have to use this tool because it is what we use in my work.
I hope someone can save me from the accumulated frustration that I have with this...

Comment: PHPStorm Help: [Configure automatic upload of changed files to the default server or server group](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/uploading-and-downloading-files.html)

Comment: You need to disable Automatic deployment (on Save) in the Deployment settings. It is OFF by default though... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#autoupload_definitions